# existe alguma função que faça a mesma coisa que o "fetch" no java?

Tags: java

preciso fazer uma requisição em uma url de uma api, mas como eu iria fazer isso no java ? já pesquisei um tal de "getch" mas não sei se funcionaria, o que posso fazer para fazer essa requisição em java ?

Comment: Sua pergunta é muito aberta, existem vários conceitos e objetivos para um fetch, sugiro melhorar sua pergunta

Comment: Se não me engano ele quer algo com JavaScript Fetch API. Se for o caso informo que mesmo em JS essa API não é adequada para o suso pretendido, em JS seria `XMLHttpRequest` ou então `JQuery.ajax()`.  Em Java essa função de solicitar a resposta de um servidor é desenpenhada pelo objeto [HttpRequest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/incubator/http/HttpRequest.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ola pra começa de facto a sua pergunte esta muito aberta, mas penso ter percebido o ideal na sua situação seria de facto usar algo para gerir HTTP REQUESTS

O RetroFit 2 pode ajudar-te nao e nada de complicado mas eu pessoalmente demorei um pouco a entender que esse framework faz o handle todo por nos

No entanto e necessario criar uma classe que sera a sua interface e outras classes para cada modelo e cada chamada ao API

Este [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JGvDUlfk7Y) pode te ajudar

Pequeno tips se a tua API retorna algo em JSON aconselho-te a usar este link [aqui](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) para criar as classes modelo

(Pra saber como e retornada a informação podes usar o Postman)

Espero ter ajudado